# Graphviz is drawing DAGs with missig arrows and circle frames of the nodes

Tags: r, bnlearn, r-graphviz

I'm experimenting with bnlearn R library and its DAGs. I'm new to R as well.

I tried the code example [here](https://www.bnlearn.com/examples/graphviz-plot/)

```
> tree = model2network("[A][B|A][C|A][D|A][E|B][F|B][G|C][H|C][I|C]")
> graphviz.plot(tree, layout = "dot")
```

but then I got this drawing!

[image]bnlearn.com/examples/graphviz-plot/

It is missing arrows and circles... How can I fix that?

sessionInfo() output:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/razan/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8          
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8        LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8          LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8           LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8       
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8      LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bnlearn_4.6.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.27       grid_3.6.1          jsonlite_1.7.2      magrittr_2.0.1      stats4_3.6.1       
 [6] evaluate_0.14       graph_1.64.0        stringi_1.5.3       rlang_0.4.10        Rgraphviz_2.30.0   
[11] rmarkdown_2.6       tools_3.6.1         stringr_1.4.0       xfun_0.20           yaml_2.2.1         
[16] parallel_3.6.1      compiler_3.6.1      BiocGenerics_0.32.0 htmltools_0.5.1.1   knitr_1.31
```

Comment: Plots fine for me. Can you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question please.

Comment: @user20650 I've added it

Comment: Thanks. I suspect it is something to do with the conda release ... I've never used this (and tend to see issues with it on this site). I suppose you could upgrade R to 4.0.3 (3.6.1 is about 18 months old) and reinstall bnlearn & Rgraphviz and see if it helps. Otherwise Id reach out to the conda folks